# ApiGateway ignores my Request Validator querystring constraints

Tags: amazon-web-services, validation, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

To put it simple I have a Cloudformation containing these two resources (hiding some names for privacy reasons):

```
  MethodRequestValidator:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator
    Properties:
      Name: !Join ['_', [ !Ref Team, !Ref Project, !Ref Environment, api, requestvalidator, !Ref Component ]]
      RestApiId: !Ref ValidatorAPI
      ValidateRequestBody: false
      ValidateRequestParameters: true

  Method:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: GET
      ResourceId: !Ref ValidatorResource
      RestApiId: !Ref ValidatorAPI
      ApiKeyRequired: true
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      RequestValidatorId: !GetAtt MethodRequestValidator.RequestValidatorId
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.querystring.example1: true
        method.request.querystring.example2: true
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Credentials: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${Team}-${Project}-${Environment}-role-execution"
        Uri: !Sub
          - arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt ValidatorFunction.Arn
      OperationName: Validator retrieve method
```

It's a simple ApiGateway linked to a Lambda, it works fine but it straightly ignores the **RequestParameters** constraint I'm putting on the query params **example1** and **example2**.

I can call the ApiGateway URL just fine and see the response from my lambda being returned, but there's no validation whatsoever on these querystring parameters, I can call the api without even inserting these two.

Comment: Are you seeing these parameters as "required" in the AWS console? Does the call get rejected if you make it through the "Test" tab on the method's page without providing the parameters? Have you deployed your method to a stage (`AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment`)?

Comment: @Quassnoi yes, I see them as required in AWS Console, I can't use the Test tab because in the current environment I'm working with I can only interact with the console through Cloudformation templates, so I can't actually change anything directly from the console. I have deployed my stage, so yes there's a deployment resource is my Cloudformation, everything works in terms of reachability, it's just these two parameters constraint that are ignored.